# Create a table dynamically depending on the number of columns - Angular

Tags: html, angular, dynamic, html-table

I want to create a table dynamically depending on the number of columns in Angular,to display the contents of a list of objects. For this, I have a variable numberOfColumns.I create a method that injects this HTML table in my HTML component, but I can't apply CSS style to   content and routerLink in this  not working. Is there any possibility
to use *ngFor *ngIf in html component to create this dynamic table?

```js
capacity = 60;//hard-coded for exemple
  noOfCol = 4 ; // hard-coded for exemple
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createTable();
  }

 createTable() {
    let _t = 0;
    let tableString: string = "<table class=\"table\" id=\"myTable\"><tbody><tr>";
  
    for (let _i = 1; _i <= this.capacity ; _i++) {

       if(_i % this.noOfCol !=  0){
          
          tableString = tableString +"<td>" +  "ob.name..."  + "</td>";
          
       }else{
           tableString = tableString +"<td>" + "ob.name... "  + "</td>" + "</tr><tr>";
    
       }
      
    }

    tableString = tableString + "</tbody></table>";

    (<HTMLSpanElement>document.getElementById("tableArea")).innerHTML = tableString;
}
```

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Building UI in Angular using the TypeScript like that is a bad practice.
For that you have all the angular power in *ngIf, *ngFor, ngTemplate, ngContainer, string interpolation etc...

You should avoid using `document.getElementById()` and all the element string that you are using => `let tableString: string = "<table class=\"table\" id=\"myTable\"><tbody><tr>";`.

Now for your question:
You can build dynamin tables in angular by using the `*ngFor` directive
and for list of object I would use the `keyValue` pipe.
That way you cay seperate the logic from the Ui and use class directly from the HTML.

I wrote some example connected to your problem:

Ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  //The object that we use to build the table
  myObjectList = [
    {
      "firstName": "Imri",
      "lastName": "Harlev",
      "gender": "male"
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Tony",
      "lastName": "Stark",
      "gender": "male"
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Bob",
      "lastName": "Jones",
      "gender": "male"
    },
  ]
}
```

HTML:

```
<table class="table-class">
  <tr *ngFor="let obj of myObjectList">
    <td *ngFor="let keyValue of obj | keyvalue">
      {{keyValue.value}}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSCC (in my case):

```
.table-class {
    border: 1px solid black;
    tr {
        td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            background-color: aqua;
        }
    }
}
```

[output exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jJ7z.png)